# PHP Imagick crop image with negative offset and keep negative space

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm using php Imagick::cropImage and i'm having some trouble.

Let's say I have this image:

[image: Test Image]

And I want to crop the image with this crop area:
[image: Image Crop Area]

This is the PHP code I am using:

```
$width = 200;
$height = 200;
$x = -100;
$y = -50;

$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage($path_to_image);
$image->cropImage( $width, $height, $x, $y );
$image->writeImage($path_to_image);
$image->clear();
$image->destroy();
```

The result is a 50px x 150px image (which is not what I want):

[image: Image Crop Result]

What I want is a 200px x 200px image with alpha to fill in the rest (checker pattern illustrates transparent pixels):

[image: Image Crop Desired Result]

How do I fill those empty pixels?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Imagick::extentImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.extentimage.php) after cropping to grow the image to the expected image size. Filling the "empty" pixels is easy with either setting the background color, or flood filling as needed.

```php
$width = 100;
$height = 100;
$x = -50;
$y = -25;

$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage('rose:');
$image->cropImage( $width, $height, $x, $y );
$image->extentImage( $width, $height, $x, $y );
```

[image: crop with negative offset]

Fill empty pixels with background

```php
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage('rose:');
$image->setImageBackgroundColor('orange');
$image->cropImage( $width, $height, $x, $y );
$image->extentImage( $width, $height, $x, $y );
```

[image: fill with background color]

or ImagickDraw

```php
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage('rose:');
$image->cropImage( $width, $height, $x, $y );
$image->extentImage( $width, $height, $x, $y );

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor('lime');
$draw->color(0, 0, Imagick::PAINT_FLOODFILL);
$image->drawImage($draw);
```

[image: fill with draw]

#### Edit

For setting transparent empty pixels, set matte before background color

```php
$image->setImageMatte(true);
$image->setImageBackgroundColor('transparent');
```

Comment: Aha! I figured there was a straight forward way to do it.  Thanks for the great reply!  What if I want to fill the background with transparent pixels?  I tried $image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent')); with no luck (pixels are white) - and the file format is .png.  I even add $image->setImageFormat("png32"); to make sure.

Comment: Ah, for transparent you need to enable the matte before setting background color. I'll updated my answer

Comment: Lovely solution. Thanks for saving my day. +1